# Postgres replication

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

Right now I have a database (about 2-3 GB) in PostgreSQL, which serves as a data storage to RoR/Python LAMP-like application.

What kind tools are there that are simple and robust enough for replication of the main database to a second machine?

I looked through some packages (Slony-I and etc.) but it would be great to hear real-life stories as well.

Right now I'm not concerned with load balancing and etc. I am thinking about using simple Write-Ahead-Log strategy for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not doing replication, Write ahead Logs are the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you can upgrade to pg 9 I would looking to streaming replication - very simple setup. Or if you can't upgrade you can just look at a hot-standby (which you can query to).

See here: http://eggie5.com/15-setting-up-pg9-streaming-replication

Comment: I realize that for replication to work, it has to be the same architecture. However, if both PGSQL are 32-bit build, but one server is 64-bit OS, and another 32-bit OS, will the replication still work? After all, as long as the SQL are both 32-bit, it should be fine right?